# How to test a top-level method?

Tags: python-3.x, testing

I have situation similar to this:

```
def my_fun(x):
    # do some stuff to x and put it in y
    y = x+1

    heavy_function(y)
```

`heavy_function` is a very complicated calculation. I wish to test only the top part of `my_fun` in `test_my_fun`, while `heavy_function` can be tested in its own test method.

I know I could extract the relevant piece of `my_fun` into a third function and then test that, but that seem like it would complicate my code base unnecessarily. I would much rather pass a fake `heavy_function` to `my_fun`, which gives (for instance) pre-computed results for the inputs that will be used to test `my_fun`.

Can this be done in Python?

Comment: You could refactor `my_fun` so that it takes a function parameter, Normally you would pass it `heavy_function`, but you could pass it some dummy function for testing purposes.

Comment: Remember `--dry-run` parameter in bash? That can be also a pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at python [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). You can do this:

```
from unittest import mock

def test_my_fun(self):
    with mock.patch(`file_path.heavy_function`, return_value = foo):
        self.assertEqual(my_fun(x), bar)
```

This mocks out whatever function you'd like so you can compare to expected return value to what you expect `my_fun` as a whole would return.